# How to list DISTINCT values of attributes and their element values?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a XML code with a long list of  tags, and I want to list every value in their  tag, and their respective "form" attribute value. **ALL DISTINCTS**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you think "distinct values" in XSLT 1.0, think "keys" and Muenchian grouping.

Example:

**XML Input**

```
<messages>
    <text>
        <corr form="Hello">Helo</corr> I'll see you next <corr form="week">wk</corr>.
    </text>
    <text>
        <corr form="Hello">ello</corr>, are you ready <corr form="for">forr</corr> this <corr form="week">weeeek</corr> end?
    </text>
    <text>
        <corr form="Hello">ello</corr> again!
    </text>
</messages>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:key name="forms" match="corr" use="@form"/>
    <xsl:key name="values" match="corr" use="normalize-space(.)"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <html>
            <table>
                <xsl:for-each select="//corr[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('forms',@form))]">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="@form"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('forms',@form)[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('values',normalize-space(.)))]"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>                
            </table>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="corr">
        <xsl:if test="position() != 1">, </xsl:if>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<html>
   <table>
      <tr>
         <td>Hello</td>
         <td>Helo, ello</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>week</td>
         <td>wk, weeeek</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>for</td>
         <td>forr</td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</html>
```

Comment: Oh thanks, but the second column elements are not distincts (though, it doesn't apply on the little XML example I put in the question..)

Comment: @Nicolas - Sorry about that. I tested with a 2.0 processor. I fixed the typo and it should work now. (Tested with Xalan and Saxon 6.5.5)

Comment: @Nicolas - If the values also need to be distinct, you can add another `xsl:key`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @Nicolas - I made another edit to normalize space. Try it again. If there are still issues after that, please update your question with some XML input I can reproduce the issues with.